# Finding PID and Base Address in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, codeblocks

I'm trying to write a code in C++ which would display a process ID and base address of some application, PID seems to look correct but base address is 0, which is incorrect. My question is - what's wrong here?

IDE: Code::Blocks

Also to make it even run i had to set up "-lpsapi" in 
Settings -> Compiler -> Linker settings -> Other linker options

I was thinking about building this as admin but could't find such option in Code::Block (maybe build-in?)

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJ04Z.png)

[Build messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbjPF.png)

```
#define WINVER 0x0501
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Psapi.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

using namespace std;

HANDLE GetHandle()
{
    string name = "PathOfExile_x64.exe";
    DWORD pid = 0;

    HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    PROCESSENTRY32 process;
    ZeroMemory(&process, sizeof(process));
    process.dwSize = sizeof(process);

    if (Process32First(snapshot, &process))
    {
        do
        {
            if (string(process.szExeFile) == name)
            {
               pid = process.th32ProcessID;
               break;
            }
        } while (Process32Next(snapshot, &process));
    }

    CloseHandle(snapshot);

    if (pid != 0)
    {
        cout << "pid = " << pid << endl;
        return OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);
    }


    return NULL;
}

HMODULE GetModule()
{
    HMODULE hMods[1024];
    HANDLE pHandle = GetHandle();
    DWORD cbNeeded;
    unsigned int i;

    if (EnumProcessModules(pHandle, hMods, sizeof(hMods), &cbNeeded))
        {
        for (i = 0; i < (cbNeeded / sizeof(HMODULE)); i++)
        {
            TCHAR szModName[MAX_PATH];
            if (GetModuleFileNameEx(pHandle, hMods[i], szModName, sizeof(szModName) / sizeof(TCHAR)))
            {
                string wstrModName = szModName;

                string wstrModContain = "PathOfExile_x64.exe";
                if (wstrModName.find(wstrModContain) != string::npos)
                {
                    CloseHandle(pHandle);
                    return hMods[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}


int main()
{
    HWND WindowHandle = FindWindow(nullptr, "Path of Exile");
    DWORD PID;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(WindowHandle, &PID);
    PVOID hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, 0, PID);

    HMODULE Module = GetModule();
    DWORD BaseAddress = (DWORD)Module;

    cout << BaseAddress << endl;

}
```

Comment: Building as admin shouldn't make a difference, but running as admin may. Please check out the used functions in the MSDN, in particular with respect to the way they signal errors. There, you should also find `psapi` as the name of the library you had to link with.

Comment: Base address should not be cast to DWORD.  Read compiler warnings.

Comment: Is there some mistakes in the process of data conversion?

Comment: `GetHandle` returns a `nullptr`, unless you are running the code with sufficient privileges. You need those privileges since you are requesting `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` for no obvious reason. Both debugging the code as well as handling errors would have given this away instantly.

Comment: Even with sufficient privileges I'm still getting wrong base address.

Comment: Note that you are reading a x64 process, and is your console process x64 as well? If not, `EnumProcessModules` will fail and GetLastError will return 299(`ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY`)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this, tested working.  I'm not familiar with the Enum functions, I prefer to use the ToolHelp32Snapshot function

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

DWORD GetProcId(const char* procName)
{
    DWORD procId = 0;
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        PROCESSENTRY32 procEntry;
        procEntry.dwSize = sizeof(procEntry);

        if (Process32First(hSnap, &procEntry))
        {
            do
            {
                if (!_stricmp(procEntry.szExeFile, procName))
                {
                    procId = procEntry.th32ProcessID;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Process32Next(hSnap, &procEntry));

        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnap);
    return procId;
}

uintptr_t GetModuleBaseAddress(DWORD procId, const char* modName)
{
    uintptr_t modBaseAddr = 0;
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, procId);
    if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        MODULEENTRY32 modEntry;
        modEntry.dwSize = sizeof(modEntry);
        if (Module32First(hSnap, &modEntry))
        {
            do
            {
                if (!_stricmp(modEntry.szModule, modName))
                {
                    modBaseAddr = (uintptr_t)modEntry.modBaseAddr;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Module32Next(hSnap, &modEntry));
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnap);
    return modBaseAddr;
}

int main()
{
    DWORD procId = GetProcId("PathOfExile_x64.exe");

    uintptr_t modBase = GetModuleBaseAddress(procId, "PathOfExile_x64.exe");

    std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << modBase << std::endl;
    std::getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I changed your code so that instead of displaying it on screen it saves it in text file. Got result "0x0" which is wrong. I did run with admin priv. so I don't understand what's going on. Also I had to remove `#include "stdafx.h"` because it was making errors and removing it didn't make any new errrors. Any ideas on what might be wrong? `DWORD procId = GetProcId("PathOfExile_x64.exe");` this has to be exe file name or window name?

Comment: @MiłoszTomkiel are you compiling as x64?  You need to.  GetProcId takes a filename, yes.

Comment: I compile your code as you say but it doesn't work. I'm messing with this finding PID several weeks. At last could you compile it yourself and send me download link please? Maybe it'll work that way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MiłoszTomkiel run as x64, run as admin, multibyte character set, just tested it and it works fine.  the exe is PathOfExile_x64Steam.exe now, it changed

Comment: So it seems like it works for PoE from Steam using `PathOfExile_x64Steam.exe` but for standalone application, `PathOfExile_x64Steam.exe` nor `PathOfExile_x64.exe` works. Even though the module name clearly says: `PathOfExile_x64.exe`.

Comment: I've done some more debugging and the line that makes error is this `HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, procId);` and the error message: `'TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32' was not declared in this scope` even though I had included `<tlhelp32.h>`. If I put these values manually the function returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. And by manually I mean `0x00000008 | 0x00000010` instead of `TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32`